# Database connection works for Cassini, but fails for IIS

Tags: sql-server, security, iis

I'm connecting to a remote database. The connection works for ASP.NET Development Server, but is failing since I switched to using IIS. Here's my connection string:

```
<add name="ConnectionString"
    connectionString="Server=SQL-NWSS-048\SHRDDEV01;Database=PESTS;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: The connection string is in my text, but isn't showing up. The toolbar isn't showing up, so I can't format it as code.

Comment: Make sure that whatever account your appPool is running under has permission to access that database. If if you want to use a SQL account you can test is by logging in with that account.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Hunter. I'm using a SQL account now, and that works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cassini, the web site is running under your account.  Since your account has rights to the database, it works, as you're using Windows Integrated security to access the SQL Server.  (Trusted Connection=True).

In IIS, unless you configure it differently, it runs under the **<Server Name>\Network Service** account, which is a local account on that server. Odds are that account doesn't have access to the database.

See [How to: Access SQL Server Using Windows Integrated Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx)

That's relatively difficult compared to using SQL Server authentication instead.  I'd recommend using SQL Server authentication, where you pass in a username/password if your situation allows for it.  Just be sure to [encrypt the connection strings in the web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28VS.80%29.aspx).